# Cisco ASA 5505: Clean delete of IPSec tunnel

Tags: cisco-asa, cisco-vpn

What is the easiest way to delete a Site2Site IPSec tunnel?
The ASDM seemingly does not offer that functionality. I have to go to various tabs to delete the different elements that were created by the vpn wizard.
The IPSec/IPSec Rules tab does not even accept changes (apply button does not activate after changes, just saving doesn't do anything either)

```
ASDM Version    5.2(4)  ASA Version 7.2(4)
Java Version    1.7.0_17    OS  Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
```

Is there a way, maybe in the cli, to delete an IPSec tunnel with its associated config parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to find all the appropiate config, and delete it by hand. CLI will be the easiest for that. First, read out the current config. An easy way to get a decently readable version, is going to `https://<ip-of-ASA>/exec/show run` in your browser (including spaces).
Copy paste all config that has to do with the tunnel. Now go into the CLI and remove all config that needs removing.
As an aside: 7.2 is an ancient version of ASA. Released April 2008. An ASA 5510 will support at least 8.2, and depending on the amount of RAM even 9.1. The ASDM has gotten a lot better since then.